# Highlight a subsequent range of cells based on previous cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to highlight a range of subsequent cells within a row if the previous cells value is a specific letter.

For example, if cell D5 contains 'F', then that cell and the subsequent 10 cells (E5:N5) will turn red. This needs to  work for every cell in an array - say A1:F500

I've tried conditional formatting with custom formulas to no avail,  and am now turning to a script format. I was thinking of assigning an IF function that runs through the array and then does the above command?

Comment: There is not much anyone can tell you without seeing your sheet. Please consider making a copy of your sheet and sharing the link here, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." My gut (and experience) tells me that you can do this with CF and that you do not need a script.

Comment: Update: I am not positive that this can be done with custom CF. Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet, and I will apply the formula there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

To do so, in your desired Spreadsheet's menu bar head over to **Tools-> Script editor** and use the following functions below. If you already have your values set in your sheet you can use the first function. If you are going to set this `F` values on the go then the second will provide support for that too. In the first we simply iterate over the range to check where the condition meets and change the background colours of the subsequent cells.

> Please note that if your range does not start from A1 you must add the n row and n column it is starting from to `sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1,1,10).setBackground('red');`. For example if you start from `D3` it would look like this `sheet.getRange(i+1+3,j+1+2,1,10).setBackground('red');`

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the desired sheet of your Spreadsheet where you want this functionallity
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Get values of your desired range
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:I20').getValues();
  
  // iterate over each row and over each column within that row
  for(i=0;i<range.length;i++){
    
    for(j=0;j<range[i].length;j++){  
      // If the value on cell with row i and column j is F
      if(range[i][j]==='F'){
        // Set the background colour of the next 10 cells in that row
        // Also note that i+1 and j+1 because we iterate in the for loop from i=0, j=0
        sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1,1,10).setBackground('red');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

The second function function takes use of a simple trigger `onEdit()` which is basically a type of function that will detect any edit change in your sheet such as the change of value in a cell. When such a change is detected, you can get the value of this cell by looking at the event that triggered this change `e` and get its range and value.

Finally you would just need to select your desired range from the detected column and row the change happened and then you can set the background colour of this range.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the desired sheet of your Spreadsheet where you want this functionallity
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // if the changed cell value is equals to your condition
  if(e.range.getValue()=='F'){
    // set the next 10 columns in the changed row to a red background
    sheet.getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), e.range.getColumnIndex(), 1, 10).setBackground('red');
  }
}
```

#### References

- [OnEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [setBackground](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks so much! That second piece of code is exactly what I needed! - I assume  you can play around with the colour variation using RGB formats for script?

Comment: Yes of course, you can use any hex value for the colour, glad I could help :D